# Is this question on-topic on Mathematics.SE?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Today, an interesting question was asked on [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com): [How to speak mathematics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45663/how-to-speak-mathematics)

Is this kind of questions on-topic on Mathematics.SE?

Comment: The OP (of the question on english.SE) asked about this question in chat. I mentioned [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35496). As to whether we have duplication, I'll leave others to judge...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's okay to ask for the standard terminology or "pronunciation" of a mathematical formula in English. It's a bit on the edge, though, I think.